# How to pass a value from one class of django models to another?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to get the name of the table that I have to download and get the fields from that table in my next form. In order to get the fields I have to first pass the name of the table that I want to download then it loads the data from that field. But I don't know how that works.

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from survey_a0 import details, analysis                                                                              
#Backend coding module
import ast

class HomeForm3(models.Model):

    Survey= models.CharField(choices=[('A','A'), ('B','B')],default='A')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class HomeForm1(models.Model):

    details.loadData(Survey)#<===== *** I need to pass the variable from above here ***
    global f1
    f1=analysis.getQuestion(in_json=False)  
    d=list(f1.keys())

    for k in d:
        q=list(f1[k].keys())
        q.sort()
        choices=tuple(map(lambda f: (f,f),q))
        locals()[k]=MultiSelectField(max_length=1000,choices=choices,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to study Django a bit more.

The usual approach is to pass an ID or other unique identification though the URL, and to use relationships in the database to tie tables together. So for example, you might have one table of `Survey`s, each of which has `Question`s  linked to it as Foreign Keys (so any Survey can access its questions as `question_set` by default). In turn each question will have `Answer` items linked to it, and the `Answer` items might also link to a logged-in `User` who supplied them.

Anyway, you might have as URL something like `surveys/analyze/329` and the URLconf for the analyze view would parse out 329, which would be the id of a Survey object. You coould then iterate over all of its questions, and within each iteration retrieve all Answers for that question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey you are right. But could you give me a quick fix?
Can I use ForeignKey?

Comment: @PRATHAMESH dozens -- use Google! -- but https://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter08.html covers everything that might answer this question. Suggest you start reading at the beginning, though.

Comment: It occurs to me to add, make sure that whatever resource you learn from matches whatever version of Django you have to use. URL parsing changed dramatically between Django 1.11 and Django 2.0. Other things, at various stages in the 1.x release cycle. Out of date documentation is a curse -- unless you are forced to use (say) Django 1.11 by your employer, in which case Django 2+ documentation will be confusing!